# Retornar cabeceras y detalles en una sola consulta

Tags: sql-server

Tengo dos tablas: **c_albaran** y **d_albaran** como bien indican, son cabecera y detalle de albaranes.
La relación entre ambas es mediante su claves **c_albaran.numero**,**c_albaran.letra** y **d_albaran.numero**, **d_albaran.numero**.
El caso es que me gustaria mostrar en una sola consulta grupos de cabecera+ lineas tal que así:

```
SF 43 14/03/2022 NomCliente 
stc234 descripcion 3
art345 descripcion 2
art123 descripcion 1
SF 43 15/03/2022 NomCliente 
asr234 descripcion2 3
frg345 descripcion2 2
art343 descripcion2 1
```

Con mis pocos conocimientos de Sql, lo único que se me ocurre, es mediante un cursor,
pero no creo que eso sea ni lejanamente lo más óptimo y con `union` no obtengo lo que esperado, he intentado con subconsultas, pero es obvio que no lo estoy haciendo bien.
¿Alguien me puede echar un cable?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: No, de la base de datos solo puedes obtener un resultado tabular plano, no hay encabezados ni títulos ni nada parecido, eso es tarea de la capa de presentación. En el mejor de los casos, si te sirve podrías, mostrar una tabla que combine la información de las dos tablas

Comment: Si te entiendo bien, solo me es posible un resultado que conste de todas las cabeceras y después de esta todas las líneas (con UNION), pero no puedo mostrar cabecera lineas, cabecera líneas etc..?

Comment: Puedes mostrar todo, pero no en el formato que buscas, a lo sumo: `tabla1.col1, tabla1.col2, tabla2.col1, tabla2.col2`, el motor de datos solo se encarga de devolver datos tabulares, no tiene ninguna facilidad de "reporting", que en definitiva es lo que estás buscando.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias.